# aggregate match $expr with combinations of $divide $mod and $floor not working

Tags: mongodb

I have been trying to figure this out on my own but can't seem to understand why it won't work. The error I get is "Expected [ or Aggregation Stage but { found".

I tried different combinations of this code and if used alone floor works in $expr, if used alone also $mod works in $expr, Somehow the whole code is not correct

```
[
{"$match":
    {"$and":
        [
         {"report_id":150},
         {"odometer":{"$gte":0,"$lte":50000}},
         {"$expr":{
            "$eq":[
                {"$mod":[{"$floor":{"$divide":["$odometer","1512.58"]}},10]},
                0
                  ]
                  }
         }
        ]
    }
},
{"$sort":{"odometer":1}},
{"$project":{"_id":0,
"lat":{"$convert":{"input":"$latitude","to":"double"}},
"lng":{"$convert":{"input":"$longitude","to":"double"}}}}
]
```

I mention that this is inside a match stage, i need the modulus of the odometer/1512.58 to be 0

Comment: what mongo version are you using?, the query itself is fine for mongo version 3.6+

Comment: using mongod --version I get db version v4.0.6, using mongo --version I get MongoDB shell version v4.0.6

Comment: can you show your full code? i feel it might be just a minor syntax error

Comment: {
  $and: [
    {
      report_id: 150
    },
    {
      odometer: {
        $gte: 0,
        $lte: 50000
      }
    },
    {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $mod: [
              {
                $floor: {
                  $divide: [
                    '$odometer',
                    '1512.58'
                  ]
                }
              },
              10
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: if you can just edit your answer with your full code, it should include the model.aggregate part with the match expr.

Comment: yes, i was copy pasting from compass, here is the full code (but however it crashed from the match stage [
{"$match":
 {"$and":
  [
   {"report_id":150},
   {"odometer":{"$gte":0,"$lte":50000}},
   {"$expr":{
   "$eq":[
    {"$mod":[{"$floor":{"$divide":["$odometer","1512.58"]}},10]},
    0
         ]
            }
   }
  ]
 }
},
{"$sort":{"odometer":1}},
{"$project":{"_id":0,
"lat":{"$convert":{"input":"$latitude","to":"double"}},
"lng":{"$convert":{"input":"$longitude","to":"double"}}}}
]

Comment: I compose my json array in php so if it was a syntax error it would show up before I even send the json to mongo

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the entire code

Comment: the query itself is fine, i ran it in my shell and it works. it must else you do to the json object.